# How get c and android ndk suggestions in eclipse ubuntu

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

i am learning android ndk. writing c/c++ code in eclipse without suggestions is it hard. so can any one help me out with the procedure to get the suggestions.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You could use eclipse ide that's meant for c/c++ programming language. And edit code and compile code in this IDE. Since you only need to know the path to ndk-build, it does not matter which IDE you use to edit c/c++ code. In your Android project Eclipse IDE, all you care is the presence of the .a or .so or .la libraries at appropriate folders anyways.

HTH.